# Android Application closes after using "android.intent.action.CALL"

Tags: android, ussd, tel, android-phone-call

I am building an android application where I am dialing an USSD code like *123*1# using below code.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:*123*1" + Uri.encode("#"))).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Issue I am facing is my application is closing. See the below log :

```
03-06 17:49:33.404 4937-4937/**** D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-06 17:49:33.614 4937-4937/**** D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-06 17:49:33.654 4937-4937/**** D/USSDCode: *123*1#

                                                     --------- beginning of system
03-06 17:49:33.734 4937-4937/**** D/isAccessibility: false
             03-06 17:49:33.734 4937-4937/**** D/isMyWise1: false
03-06 17:49:33.734 4937-4937/**** D/isMyWise3: Access
03-06 17:49:33.774 4937-4937/**** I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e5b7389 time:17108783
03-06 17:49:35.464 4937-4937/**** V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{81dd657 token=android.os.BinderProxy@e5b7389 {****/com.databacklibrary.SIMBalanceActivity}} show : true
03-06 17:49:38.124 4937-4937/**** D/isAccessibility: false
03-06 17:49:38.124 4937-4937/**** D/isMyWise1: false
03-06 17:49:38.124 4937-4937/**** D/isMyWise3: Access
03-06 17:49:38.194 4937-4937/**** I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e5b7389 time:17113201
03-06 17:49:38.524 4937-4937/**** D/USSDCodeMsg: onAccessibilityEvent
03-06 17:49:38.524 4937-4937/**** E/Alert1: 32
03-06 17:49:38.524 4937-4937/**** E/Alert2: com.android.phone
03-06 17:49:38.524 4937-4937/**** E/Alert3: null
03-06 17:49:38.524 4937-4937/**** E/Alert4: android.app.ProgressDialog
03-06 17:49:38.524 4937-4937/**** E/Alert5: [USSD code running...]
03-06 17:49:38.764 4937-4937/**** V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{81dd657 token=android.os.BinderProxy@e5b7389 {****/com.databacklibrary.SIMBalanceActivity}} show : true
03-06 17:49:40.384 4937-4937/**** D/USSDCodeMsg: onAccessibilityEvent
 03-06 17:49:40.384 4937-4937/**** E/Alert1: 32
03-06 17:49:40.384 4937-4937/**** E/Alert2: com.android.phone
03-06 17:49:40.384 4937-4937/**** E/Alert3: null
03-06 17:49:40.384 4937-4937/**** E/Alert4: com.android.phone.MMIDialogActivity
03-06 17:49:40.384 4937-4937/**** E/Alert5: [Phone]
03-06 17:49:40.394 4937-4937/**** D/USSDCodeMsg: onAccessibilityEvent
03-06 17:49:40.394 4937-4937/**** E/Alert1: 32
03-06 17:49:40.394 4937-4937/**** E/Alert2: com.android.phone
03-06 17:49:40.394 4937-4937/**** E/Alert3: null
03-06 17:49:40.394 4937-4937/**** E/Alert4: android.app.AlertDialog
03-06 17:49:40.394 4937-4937/**** E/Alert5: [Connection problem or invalid MMI code., OK]
03-06 17:49:40.404 4937-4937/**** D/isAccessibility: false
03-06 17:49:40.404 4937-4937/**** D/isMyWise1: false
03-06 17:49:40.404 4937-4937/**** D/isMyWise3: Access
03-06 17:49:40.444 4937-4937/**** I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e5b7389 time:17115454
03-06 17:49:40.544 4937-4937/**** D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
03-06 17:49:40.544 4937-4937/**** D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 1
03-06 17:49:41.254 4937-4937/**** D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Comment: that isn't the full logcat check the filters on your logcat

Comment: that's incorrect/irrelevant log. You should see the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I am not getting any exception. My application is getting close is some android phone like samsung, vivo etc but working on some android phone like 1+, HTC etc.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I add all logcat comment.

Comment: then add try..catch , and `printStackTrace()` the caught exception

Comment: select error instead of verbose in loocat monitor that will show the error causing app to crash

Comment: @NiteshMishra E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false this is once extra line coming in error rest all is same

Comment: @NiteshMishra My application is not getting crash It is getting close

Comment: are you using ActivityOptionsCompat for transition?

Comment: @NiteshMishra No I am not using any think like this

Comment: Then i can not say until i either i ll see the code or proper logcat output. Did u try debugging?

Comment: @NiteshMishra ok

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this if it is >= marshmallow

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                "123");
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123#")));
    }
```

Check permission

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 123:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
               startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:*123#")));
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Call Permission Not Granted");
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and dont forget to add permission inside manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

for < = lollipop devices

Comment: It taking me to phone dialog and that I don't want.

Comment: then change ACTION_DIAL with ACTION_CALL and add that permission in manifest file

Comment: if you are running this on marshmallow then you will have to take permission in runtime and i think thats why you are getting error

Comment: I am asking app permission to user and then only allowing user to move forward. I some application it dose not close but in some phone it is getting close.

Comment: such as samsung, vivo, appo etc

Comment: add full logcat in your question then only we can help u

Comment: I have added all logcat

Comment: Sorry that I can't

Comment: and in your provided solution for permission I am asking run-time  permission on my splash screen to user and then let user to move forwardo

Answer (score 0):

I guess its about targetSdkVersion and [using permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#permissions). change targetSdkVersion to Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower. It probably fix the issue.

Comment: I don't think so because am taking care of permission very well and my android targetSDKVersion is 25

Comment: If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the app requests permissions from the user at run-time. So just for test, degrade targetSdkVersion to 22 or show a dialog to grant the call permission.

Comment: As I said above I am using run-time permission to user.

Answer (score 0):

try this buy calling a function call()

```
public void call() {   
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);          
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));          
        startActivity(callIntent);  
}
```

or you can try this

```
 context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*123*1" + Uri.encode("#"))).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: I am doing same as you can see In my question posted

Comment: Intent.ACTION_CALL and "android.intent.action.CALL" does returns same?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

No permission required if you want to open Dial-er pad otherwise implement above method provided by @Nitesh Mishra

Comment: I don't want to open dialer

Comment: chane ACTION_DIAL to ACTION_CALL and implement Runtime Permission  as mentioned by @Nitesh Mishra

Comment: My application is not getting crash and running in major android phone but in some android device is getting close. So I don't thinks so It is runtime permission issue or any other surrounding thing which you are suggesting